# One column (df1) compare with two column(df2) with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare one column (df1) with two columns (df2).

df1

```
name        area
Cody        California
Billy       Connecticut
Jeniffer    Indiana
Franc       Georgia
Mark        Illinois
Tamis       Connecticut
Danye       Illinois
Leesa       Indiana
Hector      Illinois
Coy         California
```

df2

```
name1   name2   points
Billy   NA        20
Cody    NA        27.5
Coy     NA        25
Danye   NA        21
Franc   NA        19
        Hector    40
        Jeniffer  30
        Leesa     20
        Mark      50
        Tamis     90
```

Output

```
name           area            points
Cody        California           27.5
Billy       Connecticut          20
Jeniffer    Indiana              30
Franc       Georgia              19
Mark        Illinois             50
Tamis       Connecticut          90
Danye       Illinois             21
Leesa       Indiana              20
Hector      Illinois             40
Coy         California           25
```

[image]

Comment: use `fillna` to update name2 col in df2, later merge both dfs

Answer (score 1):

You could try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'name': {0: 'Cody', 1: 'Billy', 2: 'Jeniffer', 3: 'Franc', 4: 'Mark', 
                 5: 'Tamis', 6: 'Danye', 7: 'Leesa', 8: 'Hector', 9: 'Coy'}, 
        'area': {0: 'California', 1: 'Connecticut', 2: 'Indiana', 3: 'Georgia', 
                 4: 'Illinois', 5: 'Connecticut', 6: 'Illinois', 7: 'Indiana', 
                 8: 'Illinois', 9: 'California'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'name1': {0: 'Billy', 1: 'Cody', 2: 'Coy', 3: 'Danye', 4: 'Franc', 
                   5: np.nan, 6: np.nan, 7: np.nan, 8: np.nan, 9: np.nan}, 
         'name2': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: 'Hector', 
                   6: 'Jeniffer', 7: 'Leesa', 8: 'Mark', 9: 'Tamis'}, 
         'points': {0: 20.0, 1: 27.5, 2: 25.0, 3: 21.0, 4: 19.0, 5: 40.0, 
                    6: 30.0, 7: 20.0, 8: 50.0, 9: 90.0}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# fill NaNs in `name2` based on `name1`
df2['name2'] = df2['name2'].fillna(df2['name1'])

# merge dfs
df_new = df.merge(df2[['name2','points']], left_on='name', right_on='name2')

print(df_new)

       name         area  points
0      Cody   California    27.5
1     Billy  Connecticut    20.0
2  Jeniffer      Indiana    30.0
3     Franc      Georgia    19.0
4      Mark     Illinois    50.0
5     Tamis  Connecticut    90.0
6     Danye     Illinois    21.0
7     Leesa      Indiana    20.0
8    Hector     Illinois    40.0
9       Coy   California    25.0
```

Alternatively, instead of merge you could use `map` to add column `points` to your first `df`:

```
df['points'] = df['name'].map(df2.set_index('name2')['points'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. what if df2 is as follows:                 
name1 name2 points
Billy         Harry 20
Cody Thomas  27.5
Coy         Eric         25
Danye Lucy   21
Franc Jeni         19
         Hector 40
         Jeniffer 30
         Leesa 20
         Mark 50
        Tamis 90

Comment: You mean that only `name1` has empty entries and `name2` is filled with `['Harry', 'Thomas', 'Eric', 'Lucy', 'Jeni', 'Hector', 'Jeniffer', 'Leesa', 'Mark', 'Tamis']`? Well, it depends, but I assume in that case you still want all non-NaN values from `name1`, viz. `['Billy', 'Cody', 'Coy', 'Danye', 'Franc']`, combined with the values from `name2` *instead of* the NaN values in `name1`, right? If so, just change: `df2['name2'] = df2['name2'].fillna(df2['name1'])` to `df2['name1'] = df2['name1'].fillna(df2['name2'])` and `name2` into `name1` in the rest of the code snippet.